# Accessing Textbox programmatically created

Tags: vb.net

I need to read a datagrid numbers of items, and programmatically add tabs to one tabControl. No problem on reading the datagrid, no problem in creating the model in the tabcontrol. So, I read the number of items, create the tabs accordingly, with all textboxes already with the correct values and so on.
At this point, the user will update some information on the tabs created, and need to click a Update button. At this point, I need to read all tabs, one by one, accessing all textboxes created, and send this to my database.
The only thing I got no result till now is “How to access these programmatically created Textboxes?

This is how I create the textboxes inside the TabControl

```
    Dim TXT As New TextBox
        TXT = New TextBox
        TXT.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(213, 25)
        TXT.Width = 303
        TXT.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Center
        TXT.Name = "TXT_02_" & tab_counter
        TXT.Text = MAT_DTCP(1) 'ABERTURA
        TXT.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromOle(RGB(128, 255, 255))
        FORM_01.TBC_DTCP.SelectedTab.Controls.Add(TXT)
```

Comment: So you can **search** for them as Tim suggests below, or declare a Form level **List(Of TextBox)** and add them to that list as you create them.

Answer (score 0):

You could use LINQ:

```
Dim allTextBoxes = From tab In FORM_01.TBC_DTCP.TabPages.Cast(Of TabPage)()
                   From txt In tab.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)()
                   Where txt.Name.StartsWith("TXT_02_")
                   Select txt
For Each txt As TextBox In allTextBoxes
    ' ...  '
Next
```